# Paint in Blender just like in a VR mask?

Tags: texture-painting

I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guu_JBTped8 on youtube and i am currently looking since few days the way I could do the same thing on Blender without VR mask.

I have a character and I would like to paint on this character in order to have a painterly / handly effect and no mesh under. But I don't want to just paint textures because I want the brush to be messy and sometimes outside the shape of my character.

I tried many ways already just like grease pencil, which is the closer way to have the same result than the video but I think the grease pencil don't give as many possibility as if I had mesh. So I tried to draw curves and to put like rectangle profile on it but it's too messy and doesn't work.

So I come to you because I didn't see any tutorial or any forum about this so it's my last solution.

Let me know if you have any idea about I could do something similar to this.